# Изменить значение переменной ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему print будет 0?

Функция load_shop() вызывается другой функцией. Короче говоря, если есть обновление, вызывается функция load_shop, которая должна изменить переменную обновления. Затем мне нужно вывести значение переменной обновления. Я новичок в этом.

```
class CheckUpdate: NSObject {
   var first_class  = ViewController()
   func name() {
      if (...) {
         self.first_class.self.load_shop();
      }
   }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var update = 0
   func load_shop() {
      self.update = 1
   }
   func print_variable() {
      print("update: \(update)")
   }
}
```

Comment: чисто как вариант - условие не выполняется) попробуйте добавиить в метод load_shop тоже принт и посмотреть будет ли вызов

Comment: @Andrew в load_shop print = update: 1

Comment: у вас все эти методы в одном классе?

Comment: @Andrew функция `name` в одном классе, функция `load_shop` и `print_variable` в другом.

Comment: а переменная где?

Comment: @Andrew в классе где load_shop и print_variable

Comment: а вы не могли бы отредактировать вопрос согласно вашей логике и добавить все детали из коментов в тело вопроса пожалуйста? а то так общей картины не видно

Comment: @Andrew обновил код

Comment: как вариант `print_variable` вызывается раньше, чем `load_shop`

Answer (score 0):

У тебя главная проблема в том, что ты написал метод name() в классе CheckUpdate,
но нигде не инициализировал экземпляр этого класса и не вызвал этот метод, тем самым у тебя метод name(), loadShop() и printVarible() не срабатывают

```
import UIKit

class CheckUpdate: NSObject {
    let firstClass  = ViewController()
    let isNeedUpdate = true
    func name() {
        if isNeedUpdate {
            firstClass.loadShop()
            firstClass.printVariable()
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //инициализируем обьект класса CheckUpdate
    let check = CheckUpdate()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //вызываем метод name() класса CheckUpdate
        check.name()
    }
    
    var update = 0
    func loadShop() {
        update = 1
    }
    func printVariable() {
        print("update: \(update)")
    }
}
```